# OpenGL drawArrays GL_QUADS gived Invalid Enum (1280)

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I am having a pretty strange error, I am rendering first some terrain and then a quad to have some reference plane in case things go wrong.

This is my most relevant code:

```
@Override
protected void compilePrograms() {
    super.compilePrograms();
    programTerrain = new Program(
            new VertexShader("data/shaders/terrain.vs.glsl").compile(),
            new TessellationControlShader("data/shaders/terrain.tcs.glsl").compile(),
            new TessellationEvaluationShader("data/shaders/terrain.tes.glsl").compile(),
            new FragmentShader("data/shaders/terrain.fs.glsl").compile()
            ).compile();

    programQuad = new Program(
            new VertexShader("data/shaders/quad.vs.glsl").compile(),
            new FragmentShader("data/shaders/quad.fs.glsl").compile()
            ).compile();

    programsCompiled();        
}

@Override
protected void init() {
    super.init();

    float[] plane = new float[] {
        -400f, -5f, -400f,
        -400f, -5f, 400f,
        400f, -5f, 400f,
        400f, -5f, -400f
    };

    //temp
    FloatBuffer dataBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16 * 16 * 16 * 3 + 4 * 3);
    dataBuffer.put(generateRandomTerrain(16, 16));
    dataBuffer.put(plane);
    dataBuffer.clear();

    buffer = new DynamicDrawArrayBuffer().create().bind().fillData(dataBuffer);
    vertexArray = new VertexArrayObject().create().bind();
    vertexArray.setAttribute(buffer, VS_POSITION, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    vertexArray.enableAttributes(VS_POSITION);

    modelMatrix.identity().translate(0f, 0f, 0f);       
    Uniforms.setUniformMatrix4(UNIFORM_MODEL_MATRIX, false, modelMatrix.writeToFloatBuffer(modelMatrixBuffer));

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);

    glPatchParameteri(GL_PATCH_VERTICES, 16);
}

@Override
protected void render(final double msDelta) {
    super.render(msDelta);

    glClearColor(25f / 255f, 25f / 255f, 112f / 225f, 1.0f);
    glClearDepthf(1f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    programTerrain.use();
    programTerrain.drawArrays(GL_PATCHES, 0, 16 * 16 * 16);

    programQuad.use();
    programQuad.drawArrays(GL_QUADS, 16 * 16 * 16, 4);
}
```

Everything I used here should be straight forward as the objects are just very simple wrappers around OpenGL, Í do list the `drawArrays` for further reference:

```
public Program drawArrays(final int mode, final int offset, final int count) {
    assertCompiled();
    assertUsing();
    GL11.glDrawArrays(mode, offset, count);
    return this;
}
```

The error I get is the following:

```
Chosen display mode: 1920 x 1080 x 32 @60Hz
Started OpenGL with the following parameters:
Major version: 4
Minor version: 4
Forward compatible: true
Profile Core: true
jan 26, 2014 9:19:20 PM pkg3dgame.Controller start
SEVERE: null
org.lwjgl.opengl.OpenGLException: Invalid enum (1280)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Util.checkGLError(Util.java:59)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glDrawArrays(GL11.java:1205)
    at programs.Program.drawArrays(Program.java:87)
    at pkg3dgame.FPSGameController.render(FPSGameController.java:124)
    at pkg3dgame.Controller.renderImpl(Controller.java:208)
    at pkg3dgame.Controller.start(Controller.java:150)
    at pkg3dgame.FPSGameController.main(FPSGameController.java:210)
```

Strangely enough the code *does* work when I pass in `GL_TRIANGLES` or `GL_LINE_STRIP` for example, I am using LWJGL in case someone is wondering.

Update in debug mode: `Could not locate symbol glVertexWeighthNV`, not sure what it means.

Comment: @ratchetfreak For use in tesselation they are still completely fine, I hope? As in `layout(quads, equal_spacing, cw) in`

Comment: They work for tessellation, primitive assembly (geometry shader) occurs after tessellation so the fact that only triangles/lines/points are supported by primitive assembly is not a big issue. Also, quads in tessellation shaders refer to patch input; the output of a quad patch can trivially be decomposed into triangles.

Comment: To put that another way: `GL_QUADS` is deprecated as a primitive type, `GL_PATCHES` is how you communicate patches to TCS. Tessellation shaders accept quad patches, and conceptually generate quads as output, but the quads are broken into triangles before passed to primitive assembly (geometry shaders).